# Should I wait until next year to convert my IRA to Roth?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, roth-ira, roth-conversion

I'm considering changing my IRA into a Roth IRA. As I understand it, I'll need to pay taxes on all the money I convert. Since the tax brackets for next year will be lowered across the board, does it make sense to wait until next year to convert (assuming I make roughly the same amount next year)?

Comment: Didn't they go down just  a few days ago?

Comment: By "next year" do you mean 2018? I know of no pending changes between 2018 and 2019 tax brackets.

Comment: Taxes due in April 2018 will have the 2017 tax rates. Taxes due in April 2019 will have the new rates. I *think* that if I roll over now I end up paying the old rates, but please correct me if I' m wrong @DStanley

Comment: If you contribute to an IRA today you can claim it on _either_ your 2017 or 2018 taxes, which I _think_ applies to a rollover as well, but haven't found anything definitive yet.

Comment: I was wrong. The deadline for _conversion_ is Dec. 31, so the tax owed based on the conversion will be 2018 "income" and subject to the new brackets.

Comment: Note that the day you convert it is the day in which future gains become tax free. If you expect the markets to continue going up, the sooner you convert the better. (And the opposite is true too- if you expect an upcoming correction, convert right after that happens.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike contributions, which can apply to the prior tax year if made through mid-April, the deadline for *conversions* is Dec. 31st, which means that they must be reported in the tax year in which they occur.

So if you converted *today*, you would report the conversion on your 2018 tax return, and it would be subject to the new tax brackets. You would not *pay* the tax for the conversion until you file in 2019, however you might consider changing your withholding (or quarterly tax payments if self-employed) to ensure that you do not have underpayment penalties.

Authoritative source ([IRS Publication 950-A](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p590a.pdf)):

No mention of a specific deadline, but the *implication* is that the conversion is taxable in the year it was made based on the instructions and the lack of any mention of an extension period like the one that exists for contributions.

[non-authoritative source](https://ndtco.com/ira-info/roth-conversion):

> ...the amount converted is added to your ordinary income for that tax year. The Traditional to Roth Conversion deadline is Dec. 31.

Comment: This sounds right. If you can just add some references Ill accept your answer

Comment: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p590a.pdf is the definitive resource, but it only _implies_ that the rollover is taxable in the year in which it occurs (since there is no mention of rollovers applying to previous tax years).